# Is it possible to assign a entire struct using a pointer and one statement

Tags: c

I have a pointer `*p` that points to a `struct S`.
`S` has various fields.

Is it possible to assign structure `S` to the structure pointed to by `*p`
using only one assignment?
OR,
do I need to assign the fields, one by one?

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Yes, you can assign structures in C.

Comment: What does "till time" mean?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570, *6.5.16.1 Simple assignment
Constraints 1 One of the following shall hold: [...] — the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a structure or union type compatible with the type of the right;[...]*

Comment: You can officially add this to the list of "try it and see wth happens". Have we *really* come so far that people have to ask stuff like this *instead* of **trying it** ?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, I'm afraid so.  Every day, posts come in with 'Explain why output is 15', or whatever. After several users have wasted half an hour just trying to get a clean compile, the poster apologizes for the typo s/he put in when transcribing from printed homework, ie. never tried it.

Comment: lol, someone after my own heart - @John Coleman Googled the exact title and got; 'About 267,000,000 results'.

Comment: I had pointer problems assigning structs between banked and non banked memory areas, so I wanted to go back to basics and ask for advice. Big mistake, obviously. This forum seems to be oriented towards those who already know everything. Thanks for all non helpful comments. Keep on down voting me. That will teach me to not disturb you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example assigns a struct using a pointer and one statement.

```
int main(void) {

    struct Foo {
        char a;
        int b;
        double c;
    } *foo, *bar;

    foo->b = 10;
    bar = foo; /* now  bar->b=10 as well */
}
```